# Ошибка при попытке удалить объект через Entiy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Не получается удалить объект с использованием Entity. Есть проект *ASP.NET MVC* и таблица в БД *MS SQL*.

В папке моделей есть два класса:

1. Класс контекста данных:

   ```
   namespace TransportDemo.Models
   {
       public class RoutContext : DbContext
       {
           public DbSet<Route> Routes { get; set; }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Класс модели, представляющий таблицу `Routes`:

   ```
   public class Route
   {
       public int ID { get; set;}
       public string summary{ get; set; }
   }
   ```

В `HomeController` есть `ActionResult`, который возвращает эту таблицу из БД (или представление, как правильно сказать?)

```
RoutContext db = new RoutContext();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<Route> routes = db.Routes;
    ViewBag.Route = routes;
    return View();
}
```

И во `Views` Index.cshtml таблица отображает данные :

```
<table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><p>ID маршрута</p></td>
        <td align="center"><p>Описание</p></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var b in ViewBag.Route)
    {
        <tr>
            <td align="center">@b.ID</td>
            <td align="center">@b.agency_id</td>
            <td align="center"><a href="/Home/Delete/@b.ID">Удалить</a></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Мне нужно удалить по ID какую-то запись, в том же `HomeController` пишу такой метод:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    Route _routeDelet = db.Routes.First(c=> c.ID==id);
    db.Routes.Remove(_routeDelet);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return ViewBag();
}
```

Получаю ошибку `Не удалось найти данный ресурс.`
В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: точку останова на строку `db.Routes.Remove(_routeDelet);` поставьте, и посмотрите чему равены `id` и `_routeDelet`.

Comment: @Bulson на точку программа вообще не попадает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь вызвать метод контроллера `Delete` обозначенный аттрибутом `[HttpPost]` с помощью *GET* запроса,
поэтому получаете ошибку *404* `Не удалось найти данный ресурс`.

Вам нужно заменить `[HttpPost]` на `[HttpGet]` (или просто убрать `[HttpPost]`, по умолчанию используется `[HttpGet]`), что противоречит [*REST*](http://www.restapitutorial.ru/lessons/httpmethods.html)

Либо каким-то образом отправлять *POST* запрос, например, с помощью форм или *Ajax*

Comment: если просто заменить на 'HttpGet' падает ошибка `Не удалось вызвать тип, не являющийся делегатом.` на строке `return ViewBag();` т.е. строку удаляет но не обновляет страницу.